# Postgres read and write external files

Tags: postgresql

I would like to use my postgres server also to serve documents and images that I don't want to store in the database for several reasons.

There is an extension for that purpose https://github.com/darold/external_file [external file](https://github.com/darold/external_file)[external file](https://github.com/darold/external_file) and changed the code a bit to serve my needs without changing the core (see below). I am using 9.5 as I expect this version to be final before I finish development ;-)

I encounter the following problems:

- Writing works quick and seems to be reliable but big files lead to out of memory (1Gig and above).
- Reading often hangs vor a very long time (select readEFile('aPath');) and is not reliable.
- Both WAL and Database quickly grow in size although no database tables are involved.

My Questions:

What is wrong with the following code? How can I exclude all those operations from WAL? Has anyone alredy written something like that and would share his development?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.writeefile(
    buffer bytea,
    filename character varying)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  l_oid oid;
  lfd integer;
  lsize integer;
BEGIN
  l_oid := lo_create(0);
  lfd := lo_open(l_oid,131072); --0x00020000 write mode
  lsize := lowrite(lfd,buffer);
  PERFORM lo_close(lfd);
  PERFORM lo_export(l_oid,filename);
  PERFORM lo_unlink(l_oid);
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.writeefile(bytea, character varying)
  OWNER TO itcms;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.readefile(filename character varying)
  RETURNS bytea AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  l_oid oid;
  r record;
  buffer bytea;
BEGIN
  buffer := '';
  SELECT lo_import(filename) INTO l_oid;
  FOR r IN ( SELECT data 
             FROM pg_largeobject 
             WHERE loid = l_oid 
             ORDER BY pageno ) LOOP
    buffer = buffer || r.data;
  END LOOP;
  PERFORM lo_unlink(l_oid);
  return buffer;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.readefile(character varying)
  OWNER TO itcms;
```

To explain my need for the above: This will be part of a medical system that also serves and stores huge documents and images through unsecure connections. storing hundreds of GB in the database doesn't seem to be a good idea to me. Since they don't change and just new docs are added backup of files is much more easy. As the database already handles SSL connections it would be great not having to deploy an additional sftp server for serving those files!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your concept is doomed to failure. You are using the database server as a cache for disk operations on large files . This is an obvious waste of time and resources because the server each time have to save the entire contents of the file to remove it for a moment.

In my opinion, the use of ftp server will be simpler, more natural and far more efficient solution.

Comment: I just want to read and write files that I also could store in the database - instead they reside in the servers file system. I don't see why a database server should not also serve this while I use the SQL database for those things that make sense. As I said, it would make deployment of my system mich more easy if I would not have to deploy and configure an additional sftp or ftps server.

Comment: Not *instead* but **additionally**. In fact, now your model is: 1. store the large file in the database (`lowrite`), 2. save it to a file (`lo_export`), 3. remove it from the database (`lo_unlink`). It makes no sense. It involves plenty of unnecessary expensive database operations, including write-ahead logging.

Comment: This I can understand, so this approach is really nonsense, I did not really understand the source of the two functions as the documentation as I am quite new to Postgres. It would be great if I could just "hand through" the binaries and they would not touch the database. Like tose   data wrappers but I did not find one for binary files like images and compressed documents.  Thanks for your explanation!